# Entity Framework Database First approach with Asp.net MVC

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Entity Framework 4.4 Database first approach with Asp.net MVC 4, i had some master tables like Country, City, i want to insert data into it, currently for validation i need to define separate model for each table. I am also using T4 template method which will generate separate class for each table.

My Simple question is how can i put all validation in DB class which generate by T4 template method, so i do not need to create separate model for each of this master tables.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the classes generated by EF as those classes will be regenerated by EF and any change you made will be lost. I think your approach is right - apply your validation on the model classes you have created (using data annotations)